# Problem with find Min and Max Value in array

Tags: c#, arrays

Develop an application with the heading “Finding the minimum
element ”, which searches for the minimum element among the maximum
elements in N one-dimensional arrays.

Number of arrays, dimension of arrays and element values
corresponding arrays are entered from the keyboard. Entering array values ​​with a search.

issue the maximum value in the array as a separate method. Search
make the minimum element among the maximum elements as a separate
methods using the params modifier.

At the end of the application the maximum values ​​of all arrays and the number should be displayed on the monitor screen
array with the minimum element value.
I don't know ,how I can do this task . Please ,help me.
My trying :

```
using System;


namespace LR9_3_
{
  class Program
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.Write("Write number of massive ");

        int ab = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i1 = 1; i1 <= ab; i1++) {
            Console.Write("Write dimension of massive " + i1+" ");
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] mass = new int[a + 1];

            for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(" Input " + i + " value ");
                mass[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            ;
            static int MinElement(params int[] array)
                {
                    int minElement = array[0];


                        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (minElement > array[i])
                            {
                                minElement = array[i];
                            }
                        }
                    Console.WriteLine("Answer is  " + minElement);

                    return minElement;
                }

           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: Is it this?: 1. Find the maximum elements in multiple N-dimensional arrays which are entered (read from stdin) 2. find the minimum of these? Which means, find the array with the lowest maximum?

Comment: By the way, `int[] mass = new int[a + 1];` does not mean n-dimensional. N-dimenaional arrays are matrices, like `int[,]` where you have `int[,] a = new int[3,4]; a[2,3] = 5;`

Answer (score 0):

LINQ already provides the [Max()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.6.2) and [Min()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=netframework-4.6.2) extension methods. You can directly use it on your array.

```
array.Min();
array.Max();
```